# Days in this month and days in this year formulas

Tags: formula, formula-field, custom-field, administration, fields

I have a formulas of days in this month and this year with start and finish dates. My formula counts the number of days in this month/year that fall in a given interval (between Start Date and Close Date). For example, I have Start Date 30.12.2018, and Finish Date 03.01.2019. Days of this (2019) year should be 2 (without last day), and days of this (May) month should be 0.

So, I'm trying to count the number of days between the Start Date and CloseDate that fall in the current Month, and the number of days between the Start Date and CloseDate that fall in the current Year.

But I have troubles with big intervals through the years.

[image]

[image]

[image]

How can I fix these formulas?

Counting days for this month:

```
IF(
    AND(
        MONTH(TODAY()) = MONTH(Start_Date__c),
        MONTH(TODAY()) = MONTH(CloseDate)
    ),
    Days__c,
    IF(
        AND(
            MONTH(TODAY()) > MONTH(Start_Date__c),
            MONTH(TODAY()) = MONTH(CloseDate)
        ),
        Days__c - (
            (
                TODAY() - DAY(TODAY()) + 1
            ) - Start_Date__c
        ),
        IF(
            AND(
                MONTH(TODAY()) = MONTH(Start_Date__c),
                MONTH(TODAY()) < MONTH(CloseDate)
            ),
            IF(
                MONTH(TODAY()) = 12,
                DATE(YEAR(TODAY()), 12, 31),
                DATE(YEAR(TODAY()), MONTH(TODAY()) + 1, 2) - 1
            ) - Start_Date__c,
            IF(
                AND(
                    MONTH(TODAY()) > MONTH(Start_Date__c),
                    MONTH(TODAY()) < MONTH(CloseDate)
                ),
                DAY(
                    ADDMONTHS(
                        DATE(
                            YEAR(TODAY()), MONTH(TODAY()), 01
                    ), 1
                ) - 1
            ),
            0
        )
    )
)
)
```

Counting days for this year:

```
IF(
    AND(
        YEAR(TODAY()) = YEAR(Start_Date__c),
        YEAR(TODAY()) = YEAR(CloseDate)
    ),
    Days__c,
    IF(
        AND(
            YEAR(TODAY()) > YEAR(Start_Date__c),
            YEAR(TODAY()) = YEAR(CloseDate)
        ),
        Days__c - (
            (
                TODAY() - DAY(TODAY()) + 1
            ) - Start_Date__c
        ),
        IF(
            AND(
                YEAR(TODAY()) = YEAR(Start_Date__c),
                YEAR(TODAY()) < YEAR(CloseDate)
            ),
            (DATE(YEAR(TODAY()), 12, 31) + 1) - TODAY(),
            IF(
                AND(
                    YEAR(TODAY()) > YEAR(Start_Date__c),
                    YEAR(TODAY()) < YEAR(CloseDate)
                ),
                TODAY() - DATE(YEAR(TODAY()), 1, 1) + 1,
            0
        )
    )
)
)
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Could you please **[edit]** your post to use words to clearly describe what you want this formula to do?

Comment: Thank you. Done

Comment: Your requirements are still not very clear. You have two date fields, and is not obvious how your formulas are supposed to interact with them.

Comment: I'm trying to count the number of days between the Start Date and CloseDate that fall in the current Month, and the number of days between the Start Date and CloseDate that fall in the current Year.

Comment: This seems like logic which would be much more easily implemented via `Apex Trigger`.

Comment: No. Trigger is tied to insert or update. This formulas work only with the date. Date's changing - isn't updating for the record. So much easier just fix these formulas.